# Why doesn't python debugger breakpoint work?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With VS Code 1.27.0 on Mac, I'm setting a breakpoint with Python debugger. I've setup a launch config to run Celery. Celery does stop in my code, if I move the breakpoint I can change what's logged before it stops. So it is stopping.

However the VS Code UI does not show that its stopped, and I cannot inspect anything or do anything. VS Code launches celery something like this:

`cd /Users/bob/project ; env "PYTHONPATH=/Users/bob/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.8.0/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd" /usr/local/bin/python3 -m ptvsd --host localhost --port 49650 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/celery -A pipeline.app worker -l info -f worker.log`

I'm unclear why it needs ptvsd and ports since it's not doing remote debugging. If I make a completely stand-alone script and run it with `Python: Current File` it debugs fine.

The `launch.json` entry is like:

`{
            "name": "Python: Celery",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/celery",
            "args": [
                "-A",
                "my_module.app",
                "worker",
            ],
        },`

Comment: It might be because Celery creates multiple processes, and maybe VS Code is not seeing them all. There's some discussion about this (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/80) but it's not clear to me if it's supposed to be supported at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific debugger, celery.contrib.rdb

See if that makes it work